# How can I create text formatting widget in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How can I create a widget where we can align text which user has entered in text area ?
And also how I'm supposed to save the entered text where formatting of text should be intact in View mode as well.

[image]

Comment: Found a solution immediately after posting question. You can use https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor or https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_summernote

Answer (score 1):

Your can check this package [flutter_summernote 0.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_summernote)

it maybe helpful for  your.

[image]